# installed vb for wp7, but it is invisble in VisualStudio Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I installed vb for wp7(displayed in controll panel 'add/remove programs', but its template is invisble in VisualStudio Express.
C# templates are visible.
What is wrong with my installation?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the 7.0 tools, you must have Visual Studio Pro (or above), not Express, to use VB for WP7.  I believe that's changed with the Mango tools (which can create 7.0 apps), but I don't know if that's true or not.

Look at requirements: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9930

--randy